# Run Multiple Keras Models In A Cluster Like OAR2

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, distributed, automl

I want to build an algorithm like automl, but, don't know how to train multiple keras models simultaneously in a cluster like OAR2.

Assume that i have two different keras models like this :

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model1.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model1.add(Dropout(0.25))
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dropout(0.5))
model1.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model2.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='selu'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(Dropout(0.25))
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

How could train these two models simultaneously in a cluster?

Comment: What kind of cluster are you talking about ? Do you mean aws or Google Cloud ? Also when you say run, do you mean train or run predictions ? A little bit more information would be nice here